# Rename and combine rows in R

Tags: r, shiny, tidyr

I am trying to combine a a couple of rows into  a dataframe. So below is the code I am using to get the output dataframe.

```
myData <- reactive({
age_selected <- input$selected_age
gender_selected <- input$selected_gender
ethnicity_selected <- input$selected_ethnicity


df <- with_demo_vars %>%
  filter(age == age_selected) %>%
  filter(gender == gender_selected) %>%
  filter(ethnicity == ethnicity_selected) %>%
  pct_ever_user(type = "SM")

 #df[, c("variable",  "sum_wts", "se")]
 #interval=paste(df$ci_l,df$ci_u,collapse = "-")
 df <- mutate(df, intervals= paste("(",round(ci_l,digits = 3), round(ci_u,digits = 3),sep = "-",")"))
#   %>% c("variable", paste("mean",x), "sum_wts", "se")
 #df[c(("variable", "mean", "sum_wts", "se","x")]
```

})

The output what I get is :[image]

The output I want is a formatted and just a few fields:

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: see dplyr::select

Comment: can't you simply just rearrange your columns after you get that output?

Comment: @nak5120 I am trying to rename the fields  and combine intervals with mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Mean` and `Standard` within `mutate`, then select the wanted columns while renaming `n` and `sum_wts`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, intervals= paste("(",round(ci_l,digits = 3), 
                                  round(ci_u,digits = 3),
                                  sep = "-",")"),
             Mean = paste(mean, intervals),
             Standard = paste0(se*100, "%")) %>%
  select(variable, Mean, Standard, N = n, `Weighted N` = sum_wts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a new column with the paste function to combine the two columns `mean` and `intervals`. Then select the columns in the order you want. And then rename each column.

```
df$Mean1<-paste(df$mean,df$intervals,sep=" ")
new_df<-select(df, variable, Mean1, se, n, sum_wts)
colnames(new_df)[1]<-"variable"
colnames(new_df)[2]<-"Mean"
colnames(new_df)[3]<-"Standard"
colnames(new_df)[4]<-"N"
colnames(new_df)[5]<-"Wighted N"
```

Comment: You can simplify that last bit of code to this: `colnames(new_df)<-c("variable","Mean","Standard","N","Wighted N")` since you've already selected the columns. Also note that `select` enables you to rename as you choose columns.